# Perl CGI PHP Session Permission Denied

Tags: php, perl, session, permissions, cgi

I'm trying to get PHP session variables into a Perl CGI script.  I've got the following perl code below which seems to work in getting me the PHPSESSID which I then pass to the PHP::Session along with the directory where the session files are stored.

```
my $cookie_name='PHPSESSID'; 
my $sess_query = new CGI;
my $session_name = $sess_query->cookie($cookie_name);
my $session = PHP::Session->new($session_name,{save_path =>'/var/lib/php/session/'});
```

My problem is occuring when I get a permission denied error

> [Fri Dec  2 16:52:44 2011] upload.cgi: /var/lib/php/session/sess_417ar7qsh4sh853gqs3bj454i5: Permission denied at /var/www/html/xxx/upload.cgi line 22, referer:...

The line 22 is the `PHP::Session->new` line in the above code.

My httpd server is running as user apache and the cgi scripts are owned by apache as are all the sesssion files in `/var/lib/php/session/` so I'm wondering why wouldn't the CGI script be able to read the session files.

I read online where one person use LWP as a workaround, but that's not my preference as I feel this is something silly on permissions that I'm missing.

---

**UPDATE:** Added info - here are the session files - as you can see the session file exists and is owned by apache, but the CGI perl script can't read these:

```
-rw-------. 1 apache apache   0 Dec  2 16:58 /var/lib/php/session/sess_417ar7qsh4sh853gqs3bj454i5
-rw-------. 1 apache apache 126 Dec  2 16:58 /var/lib/php/session/sess_f39ot5ul3bu55uu7d1rg3aqq02
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/var/lib/php/session/`, and `/var/lib/php/session/sess_417ar7qsh4sh853gqs3bj454i5`? Do an `ls -l` to find out. Also, what user/group is your perl CGI running as? Keep in mind the apache config may have your CGI scripts running as a different user.

Comment: Hmm...I can verify that httpd is running as user apache, but where would I look to find if the config file has CGI scripts running as a different user?

Comment: The easiest way to find out what user/group your CGI runs as is probably the perl variables `$<`, `$>`, `$(`, and `$)`. Just print them out from your CGI. The angle-bracket ones are real and effective user id; the parentheses are real and effective group id. You'll have to look up the ids.

Comment: I for sure did not set it as different user and just grep'd the conf file for CGI or cgi or cgi-bin and nothing out of the ordinary...

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can get that...

Comment: @Ross Why not change it back to `/tmp`, run the script, then see which user the files belong to?

Comment: @TLP: /tmp probably isn't the default on Ross's distro. It isn't on Debian, for example. Having them elsewhere enhances security and makes management much easier.

Comment: @derobert Yes, I was speaking of debugging only. Since `/tmp` should be writeable by all users, you could then simply move the file to `/var/lib/php/session`. Perhaps a too simplistic fix.

Comment: When I try to output them, I'm not getting a 500 error from apache on the  following simple script: `code` use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw/:standard/;

my $msg = $<;
my $msg2 = $>;
my $msg3=$);
my $msg4 = $(;
print"Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print"<HTML><HEAD>";
print"<title></title></HEAD><BODY><b>" . $msg "," . $msg2 . "," . $msg3 . "," . $msg4 . "</b></BODY></HTML>";
exit;

Comment: derobert - not sure this could debug by moving to /tmp since I'm not trying to write to the sess file, I'm trying to read from an existing sess file..which is in /var/lib/php/session (fedora).

Comment: ok, hang on for a few minutes...I'm betting this is SELinux (AGAIN!) torturing me...standby

Comment: @Ross I said that, not derobert. You would get the same error whether reading or writing with those permissions. The question is which user is running the script. You have a syntax error in that code, messing up with the commas. Just print the whole thing inside the quotes.

Comment: @Ross: Just `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n$< $> $( $)\n";` No need for copying all the variables. Or for any complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed SELinux...and in this case, not 1 AVC alert, but 5 - one alert corresponding to each file I/O action needed to read a file in the directory.  they fire sequentially, but can be allowed using {} syntax below.

this can be solved by:

```
allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_var_run_t: dir search;
allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_var_run_t: file { lock read ioctl open getattr};
```

Talk about using a belt and suspenders!

Thanks for the help!

R

Answer (score 0):

> ...so I'm wondering why wouldn't the CGI script be able to **read** the
>   session files.

In the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP%3a%3aSession) it says:

> save_path
>
> path to directory where session files are **stored**. default: /tmp.

I don't think you and this module are thinking of the same session files.

Comment: I've highlighted "stored" for you. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: Hit edit, then click source. Alternatively, http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a7bceb5f-c86e-40d7-a746-b57e732e1fef/view-source ... your spacing made it think that second line was code, so I used &nbsp; instead.

Comment: Hi - the default is /tmp, but if you look at my constructor, I'm passing a hash array to override the default to the directory where the session files are stored on my particular machine.   The Session object understands what I want to do, but I get stopped by the permission denied....

Comment: @ross And does the apache user have write access in this directory?

Comment: Four spaces indicates a code block. Same with a tab, I believe. But apparently four &nbsp; does not. You can't format in code blocks.

Comment: Since I can't answer my own questions - here is the fix until 8hrs have expired:  allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_var_run_t: dir search;
allow httpd_sys_script_t httpd_var_run_t: file { lock read ioctl open getattr};

Comment: My guess is this would alleviate the need for this hack: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10285546